# How to open external files using flutter app?

Tags: flutter, file, launcher

How can I open other apps or files using my flutter app? Let's say, if I am going to open some photos, it asks me if I want to open them with the Gallery or other app like image viewer. Like this, I want to add an option that if I press on some file, like pdf, I want my app to be in the list of launcher apps so when it asks me to choose a launcher app, my app will be there as well.
Here is a demo image:
[image]

In android, it is working very well. But, in IOS, when I launch the app with external file, catching url of that file is getting a real problem. [Receive sharing intent package](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent) did not work for me, I have gone through docs for many times.

I used native code for android to parse uri of file to absolute path, but could not find anything efficient for iOS. Could someone please, help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`receive_sharing_intent`](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent) or [`receive_multi_sharing_intent`](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_multi_sharing_intent).

They're Flutter plugins that enable Flutter apps to receive sharing photos, videos text, URL, or any other type from other apps.

Comment: Thank you a lot )) Looks like receive sharing intent has some problems with ios.